# arrowchart - changing bar chart to shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to create an arrow chart as so:

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/arrow-charts-in-excel/

I know how to create a stacked bar chart and what not, but I'm stuck on the arrow aspect.

Does anyone know how to switch an arrow (or a triangle) in for a bar? I also thought about using a candlestick graph - but I didn't know how to use an arrow (or a triangle).

I am trying to show change by either using an up and down arrow (or up and down triangle) if the change is positive / negative, respectively.

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by drawing arrows, potentially along with a bar chart depending on what the desired effect is. For example, imagine I have data for the some variable, `y`, and its change, `dy` as tuples `(y,dy)`. An `if/else` can be used to choose color. Then I draw one arrow for each pair of `y`, `dy` in `data`.

```
data=[(.5,.5),(.8,.4),(.2,-.1)]
clrs=['green','red']
for i in range(len(data)):
    y,dy=data[i]
    if dy>0:
        c=clrs[0]
    else:
        c=clrs[1]
    arrow(i,y,0,dy,color=c,length_includes_head=True,lw=2,width=.002)

xlim(-.5,2.5)
ylim(0,2)
grid()
```

I added the grid so you could see that with the `length_includes_head` argument set to true, the tip of the arrow ends at the end of `y+dy`. Play around with the line width and width to get your desired effect.

Comment: great I've actually had to put this on hold until tomorrow, but the arrow function definitely looks like what i was going for. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modify the python codes here so that we can make a simple arrow chart with annotation. Hope it is helpful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
data=[('A',.5,.5),('B',.8,.4),('C',.2,-.1)]
clrs=['green','red']
for i in range(len(data)):
    txt,y,dy=data[i]
    if dy>0:
        c=clrs[0]
    else:
        c=clrs[1]
    ax.arrow(i,y,0,dy,color=c,length_includes_head=False,lw=2,head_width=0.05, 
head_length=0.05, width=0.01, fc=c,ec=c)
    ax.annotate(txt, xy=(i, y-dy/6),fontsize=18, 
horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment= 'center')
plt.xlim(-.5,2.5)
plt.ylim(0,2)
plt.grid()
```

[image: Arrow Chart Sample]